# How can I play a sound effect when clicking or hovering over a tag in React using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to make so that when I click or hover over a Link tag it plays a sound effect but it isn't working.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);

let allowSound = true;

export function init() {
    let a = document.querySelector('Link');
    a.addEventListener('click', select);
    a.addEventListener('mouseover', hover);
}
export function select(){
    var audioS = new Audio("./media/select.mp3");
    audioS.play();
}

export function hover(){
    var audioH = new Audio("./media/hover.mp3");
    audioH.play();
}
```

Help?

Comment: Why are you looking for a `Link` tag instead of an `<a>`?

Comment: Because I'm using react-router-dom.

Comment: Why don't you add the listener in the JSX?

Comment: I have multiple pages where I would be using these functions so instead of adding multiple event listeners in JSX I just linked all of the pages to a separate JS file that contains the event listeners, as to save on memory and speed. Cleanliness too.

Comment: Your code doesn't work because `<Link>` components render `<a>` elements in the end. So you'll have to rethink this.

Comment: Switched the Link to <a> in both JSX and query selector, still not working.

Comment: It works for me with `window.addEventListener('load', init);`

Comment: Well that helped.. sorta. Now it's displaying an error with the caption "Failed to load because no supported source was found". I checked the path and file name multiple times and it all seems fine?